# Thunderbird "Open Message in Conversation" sometimes opens different thread

Tags: email, thunderbird

I am running Thunderbird 68.10.0 on an Ubuntu 20.04 laptop.  I frequently use "Open Message in Conversation" to few the entire conversation (thread) that an email is in.  About one month ago Thunderbird started occasionally opening the wrong thread of emails when I asked it to Open the Message in Conversation.  I am not sure how to start diagnosing the problem.  What information can I provide here that would help identify and solve the problem?

thanks
brett

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the hamburger menu (top right) and then selecting File > Compact Folders to rebuild the structure?

Comment: I ran "compact folders" and then tried opening messages in conversation.  As before some work OK but some open a different email thread.

Comment: yoou then need to close TB and then locate and delete global-messages-db file. Restart TB to rebuild it. [reference](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/rebuilding-global-database)

Comment: That did it, thanks! For other users with similar linux setups the file to delete is .thunderbird/<profile_name>/global-messages-db.sqlite. <profile_name> will likely be something like "1da3hf6z.default"

Comment: Great. I'll precis that as an answer then if you would care to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I clicked on the up arrow for your answer but my reputation is not high enough for that to register publicly.

Comment: I think you can still [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) the answer by clicking the grey tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the accept icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to try is to click on the hamburger menu top right of TB then select File > Compact Folders to rebuild the structure.

If that produces no improvement then the next option is to rebuild the `global-messages-db` file.

To do this, close TB and locate and delete the `global-messages-db` file. This can be found in terminal by issuing the following command:

```
locate global-messages-db
```

This will find the file to  delete:  `.thunderbird/<profile_name>/global-messages-db.sqlite`. <profile_name> will likely be something like "1da3hf6z.default"

Restart TB and this will rebuild the file.

[reference](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/rebuilding-global-database)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and solved it by setting “Ignored Threads”:

[image: Ignored Treads]